# How can I change url structure in laravel 4?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I generated users model using laravel 4 scoffold generator.
In this i am getting url like this :   /users/1/edit

but how can i change url to : users/edit/1

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is: you can't.

Now a longer one:

Laravel implements [Rails RESTful routing pattern](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html), so if you use a pure Route::resource() is that what you gonna have.

But you have options:

1) Create your routes manually:

```
Route::get('users/edit/{id}', 'UsersController@edit');
```

[This article](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2013/07/beware-the-route-to-evil), from Phil Sturgeon shows that's better to create them all manually and this is what I particularily do.

2) Create a new class of yours, extending Router and make whatever changes you think you need to.